# How to display values in a ComboBoxEdit as 4 point decimal number in the specified format(eg: 0.0000). Required for devexpress control

Tags: c#, devexpress-wpf

Itemsource is binded to a list of string(numbers without decimal points)
Display ComboBoxEdit values as 4 point decimal number : here is the sample code

```
                        <dxe:ComboBoxEdit x:Name="Stop"
                                          Grid.Column="2"
                                          Width="250"
                                          Margin="0,6,5,15"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                                          ItemsSource="{Binding CurrentJobItem.ScanSettings[0].StopCollection}"
                                          IsTextEditable="True"
                                          AutoComplete="True"
                                          IncrementalFiltering="True"
                                          ImmediatePopup="True"
                                          EditValue="{Binding CurrentJobItem.ScanSettings[0].Stop, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus,
                                                              Converter={StaticResource JobSettingConverter}}"
                                          PreviewTextInput="NumberValidationComboBox"
                                          InputScope="Number"
                                          Validate="TextEditMaterialValidate">
                            <dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding StringFormat={}{0:0000}}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </dxe:ComboBoxEdit.ItemTemplate>
                        </dxe:ComboBoxEdit>
```

Comment: Format the `string`s the way that you want them to look *before* you put them into the `list`. You can't use numerical formatting on something that's already a string; you have to apply it as you translate it from a number (`int`, `float`, whatever) to a string.

Comment: can't we apply string format through xaml